# Natural Language Understand in a dialog

Tags: node.js, botframework

So I'm using LUIS to begin certain dialogs depending on the users Intent.

Pretend this is one of my registered dialogs:

```
bot.dialog('/sports', [
  function (session) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'What is your favorite sport?');
  }, function(session, result) {
       ....
  }
])
```

Using this waterfall, one might expect the user to just say something like "Baseball". But what if they say "My favorite sport is Baseball". Inside my waterfall, how can I determine what their true answer is, so that I can continue the dialog depending on their answer? Do I somehow plug it back into LUIS? Do some complex RegEx? Or what?

Comment: Do you await an answer in a defined list of sports ? I'm thinking of something involving having a list of every sport that the user could enter, which is quite troublesome and unprecise in certain cases...

Answer (score 0):

Give [Understanding Natural Language](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/guides/understanding-natural-language/) on the documentation a read through. Luis can be trained to recognize "intents", which are the action that the user means to convey with a natural language message. In your example, an intent might be "PreferredSport", and you'd train it with a bunch of variations on the theme of "I like baseball", "Soccer is the best", "Competitive programming is superior to all other activities.", etc. You also would train it to recognize "entities", which are tokens in the message that need to be recognized and extracted. In this case you'd have a "Sport" entity that matches to any listed sport.

The linked article will walk you through attaching your bot to your Luis recognizer.